# Increase the length of first image in graphics magick

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am trying to increase the length of first image I have three images which are merged, on first image it shows a white box below it but I want that white box to be covered with whole first image. Might be possible with increasing the length of first image, I tried using re sizing, but it didn't worked. below is the code. As in the image, a white box is there below the black image, I want black image to cover that white space, by increasing its length.

Image Illustration

```
+---+---+---+---+
| user1 | user2 |
|       |---+---+
|       | user3 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

[image]

```
        gm()
        .in('-page', '+0+0')
        .resize(50,100,"!")
        .in('http://localhost:8080/user1')
        .resize(50,100)
        .in('-page', '+50+0')
        .in('http://localhost:8080/user2')
        .in('-page', '+50+50')
        .in('http://localhost:8080/user3')
        .mosaic()
        .write('C:/images/output1.jpg', function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
```

I want this Output as an example:
[image]

Comment: You should give some image examples to illustrate source images, what you want to happen and what actually happens. It is very hard to visualise what you want from your text description.

Comment: @NeilSlater, I have edited my question

Comment: Is that what you want to happen? What shape/size are the original images that you want to place, and what actually happens? The example is OK, but might be clearer still if it used images rather than ASCII representation.

Comment: @NeilSlater, shape is square images, size of 50 by 50, there are three images which are merged, first image will be shown on left all over till end and two images will be shown up and down which are both merged and further merged with the first one. I will try to edit the question with original image.

Comment: @NeilSlater, I have updated the question with image

Comment: Can you give dimensions of the original images - it looks like they are 100x50 pixels, and you want to fit them into a 150x100 rectangle?

Comment: If that is the case, and the `user1` image would look ok rotated, it may make more sense to rotate it. Or are you OK with the fact from your example, that you only see a small part of the image, because the other 2 images are on top of it? Or is it OK to make the end result bigger = 300x100 image? None of the images in your example are 50x50 squares, so that doesn't match your description? It is important to be accurate with the numbers, otherwise no-one can answer.

Comment: @NeilSlater, I have edited my question now the images is of 50*50

Comment: @NeilSlater I want the black image to cover the left whole section

Comment: By 1) stretching/distorting it, or by 2) scaling it and having images 2 and 3 cover the left hand side or by 3) scaling it and having images 2 and 3 next to it (making the final image 150x100)?

Comment: @NeilSlater, I have tried resizing the first image but that doesn't worked. I have also edit my question by putting resize

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The image clearly doesn't fit exactly into the space. What kind of transformation do you need? The re-sizing *will* work if you get the syntax right, but it will distort the image, it will look stretched. Is that OK?

Comment: The edit *still* doesn't explain what you want!  Your example shows it *somehow* filling the space, but because you are using solid blocks of colour, it does not show what kind of transformation you are attempting. *Is it ok to distort image by stretching it?*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112864/discussion-between-jn-newbie-and-neil-slater).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with the resize is caused by mixing `.in()` methods which insert things direct on the command line with the graphicsmagic library methods which apply some extra heuristics on what to do. Adding a `.resize` attempts to resize the main graphic object (which is then ignored by `.mosaic` which sizes the final image according to the contents).

The easiest solution is to use your `.in()`-based syntax for the resize:

```
    gm()
    .in('-page', '+0+0')
    .in('-resize', '50x100!')
    .in('http://localhost:8080/user1')
    .in('-page', '+50+0')
    .in('http://localhost:8080/user2')
    .in('-page', '+50+50')
    .in('http://localhost:8080/user3')
    .mosaic()
    .write('C:/images/output1.jpg', function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

This works on my test with local images.